# why scala can't infer the type of method parameters

Tags: scala

I am wondering why scala can't infer the type of method parameters.I can see that in haskel (which also has type inference) can do the same. Then why not for scala ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all the situation in Scala is quite a bit different than in Haskell because it's an OO language and type-inference in an object oriented setting is a bit more complicated.

The only OO language that I know which comes close to full type inference is OCaml. OCaml does so by making extensive use of structural typing (the inferred type of `o` in `let f o = o.foo 42` is "Object which has a `foo` method which takes an `int` as an argument" and the inferred return type is "whatever the return type of `o.foo` is", which is the only useful type to infer here).

However Scala has many additional features (overloading, implicit conversions) that get in the way of OCaml's approach and make full, global type inference impossible.

Comment: Yes. Especially overloading is a problem for Hindley-Milner style type inference.

Answer (score 7):

To put it simply, Hindley-Milner, the type inference algorithm used by Haskell, doesn't work in the presence of subtyping.

Comment: Except a simply modified version *does* work in OCaml, which has subtyping. Of course, it's *structural* subtyping rather than Scala's nominative subtyping.